# Not a moment to be lost

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the following two sentences.

> ***There was not a moment to be lost***.
>
> ***There was not a moment to lose***.

Answer (score 3):

There is no significant difference in meaning. The "to be lost" form is slightly more formal, and perhaps a bit more old-fashioned, but neither would seem odd in current speech, I think. Yet more informal would be

> There was no time to lose.

This is not quite as forceful -- "not a moment" emphasizes that not even the smallest bit of time could be spared.